How can I sort a list using multiple ways?
I have a ScriptableObject in unity
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Food", menuName = "Prismalia/ScriptableObject/Food")]
public class FoodScriptableObject : ScriptableObject, IComparable
{
    [Header("Basic Info")]
    public string itemID;
    public new string name;

    [Header("Main food stats")]
    public string MainEffect;
    public int MainEffectValue;
    public bool MainValuePercent = false;
    public int Amount;

    [Header("Sub food stats")]
    public string SubEffect;
    public int SubEffectValue;
    public bool SubValuePercent = false;

    public string Description;

    [Header("Enums")]
    public Rarity Rarity;
    public FoodType FoodType;
    public MainFoodEffect MainFoodEffect;
    public FoodEffectsTypes MainFoodEffectType;
    public SubFoodEffect SubFoodEffect;
    public FoodEffectsTypes SubFoodEffectType;

    [Header("Visuals")]
    public Sprite MainSprite;
    public Sprite SubSprite;
    public GameObject Prefab;


    [Header("Arrays")]
    public string[] RefinementRankDescription;



    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        var a = this;
        var b = obj as FoodScriptableObject;

        if (a.Amount < b.Amount)
            return -1;

        if (a.Amount > b.Amount)
            return 1;

        return 0;
    }



}

I save a lot of them in a list on a other Scriptnd here I sort it based on the amount
if(bSort)
{
    scripts.Sort();
}

How can I make it sort acd and dec? based on the amount and how can I make it sort from a diffren variable or an enum for intance sort by rarity?
public enum Rarity
{
    Common,
    Uncommon,
    Rare,
    Epic,
    Legendary,
    Mythic
}

If any one helps please try not to use lamda typing as I dont understand lamda
I tried making a new list and coping it over to it as I have multiple scriptable objects and I save all in a normal List and get the type by GetType() then use the values

What is scripts? Some List<T>? Generally if you want to apply List.Sort(), you have to either make the objects in your list to implement the IComparable<T> interface, or you can provide a custom IComparer<T>

Providing a custom IComparer<T> has the advantage, that you can pass different IComparer implementations in different situations, depending on what ordering you would need (ascending, descending, sort by different property, ...)

Read the documentation for the Sort method. It is overloaded and allows you to pass a Comparison<T> delegate or an IComparer<T>. The former is good for one-off sorts while the latter is more reusable but both allow you to sort by any criteria you want.

Linq OrderBy, OrderByDecending etc .... not using something because you don't understand it is a bad reason imho .. learn it, you will need lambda quite often. You can btw use Linq without lambda by passing in according methods instead ;)

The standard interface for sorting is IComparer<T>. This is generic, so you have type safety, and it allow for multiple implementations to sort your items in different ways:
class FoodRarityComparer: IComparer<FoodScriptableObject>
{
    public int Compare(FoodScriptableObject x, FoodScriptableObject y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return 0;
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, y)) return 1;
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, x)) return -1;
        return x.Rarity.CompareTo(y.Rarity);
    }
}

If you want to flip the sort order, just flip x and y. If you want to sort by multiple properties you can check if  x.Rarity.CompareTo(y.Rarity) == 0, and then compare the next property. Just make sure to follow the rules of sorting.
You can sort a list by foodList.Sort(new FoodRarityComparer()) and an array by Array.Sort(foodArray, new FoodRarityComparer() )
Note that List.Sort and Array.Sort are in-place sorts and not stable. Linq.OrderBy is not in-place, but stable, and tend to be easier to use than having to create a bunch of comparer objects.

Firstly I am aware you mentioned to try and not use lamda, however I feel LINQ provides a nice solution to your problem as well as leaving it open for further functionality. I hope this example helps you understand it better.
Firstly I changed Rarity Enum to have values:
public enum Rarity
{
    Common = 0,
    Uncommon = 1,
    Rare = 2,
    Epic = 3,
    Legendary = 4,
    Mythic = 5
}

Make sure you have this: using System.Collections.Generic; and using System.Linq;
Here are some examples that achieve the asc and desc sorting as well as some other example that could be useful in the future:
public static void OrderByExample()
{
    List<FoodScriptableObject> foodsList = new List<FoodScriptableObject>();//populate this list with some data

    List<FoodScriptableObject> foodsAsc = foodsList.OrderBy(foodItem => foodItem.Rarity).ToList();

    List<FoodScriptableObject> foodsDesc = foodsList.OrderByDescending(foodItem => foodItem.Rarity).ToList();

    List<FoodScriptableObject> orderedRarityThenName = foodsList
        .OrderBy(foodItem => foodItem.MainEffectValue)
        .ThenBy(foodItem => foodItem.name).ToList();
    
    List<FoodScriptableObject> furtherOrdering = foodsList
        .OrderBy(foodItem => foodItem.MainEffectValue)
        .ThenBy(foodItem => foodItem.name)
        .ThenBy(foodItem => foodItem.SubEffect).ToList();
}

I made a function to test this locally and seems to work perfectly, you can also then remove IComparable and the CompareTo() implementation.

Firstly I changed Rarity Enum to have values: .. they already had exactly those values implicitly ;)

if the lambdas would be an issue OP could still pass in according explicit named methods instead ;)

just for OP: in comparison to IComparer / IComparable you see that Linq is way for flexible, easy to read and write. Have in mind though that you pay for that on the performance and allocations side
